# Using HTTP Request of Jmeter to put records into Amazon Kinesis

Tags: rest, http, jmeter, put, amazon-kinesis

I use jmeter to create HTTP request for my webservice REST.
Now i want to send this request to Amazon kinesis using PutRecords method but i don't know hot to create the request, in particular how to set Headers fields for Signing and Authenticating in kinesis.
Has someone used Rest request?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the header manager? http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager

Comment: yes, i used header manager but i am new in kinesis so I don't know the header name and value that i must set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is old and I don't remember all but this is the code if someone need it:
BeanShell Sampler

```
import org.MyKinesisClient;

//Create a controller object every time Jmeter starts 
MyKinesisClient controller=new MyKinesisClient(vars.get("accessKey"),vars.get("secretKey"),vars.get("endpoint"),vars.get("serviceName"),vars.get("regionId"));
bsh.shared.controller=controller;
```

This is the last code:

```
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONArray;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject;
import org.MyKinesisClient;

//Variables
int timestampValue=(${i});
String idValue=${__threadNum}+"_"+"1";
JSONObject part = new JSONObject();

//Inserimento campi Json
part.put("updated",timestampValue);
part.put("parent","${__threadNum}");
part.put("id",idValue);
part.put("thingClass","CosyInverter");
part.put("mac_address_w","${mac_address_w_1}");
//Other put
.... 

//Send Json to kinesis
MyKinesisClient controller=bsh.shared.controller;
controller.sendJson(part, ${__Random(0,${__threadNum})},vars.get("streamName"));
```

My code is more complicated than that above (database query etc...) but I hope this is what you need.

This is the java code about MyKinesisClient

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordsRequestEntry;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONArray;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Class useful to send Json to Amazon Kinesis.
 * @author l.calicchio
 *
 */
public class MyKinesisClient {
    private AmazonKinesisClient kinesisClient;

    /**
     * Class constructor. Allow all parameter setting
     * @param accessKey: access key for kinesis connection
     * @param secretKey: secret key for kinesis connection
     * @param endpoint: Kinesis endpoint 
     * @param serviceName: Amazon service name
     * @param regionId: region id of kinesis endpoint 
     */
    public MyKinesisClient(String accessKey, String secretKey, String endpoint, String serviceName, String regionId ) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials);
        kinesisClient.setEndpoint(endpoint,serviceName,regionId);
    }

    /**
     * Method useful to send the json to Kinesis
     * @param json: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject to be sent
     * @param partitionKey: partition key for Kinesis stream 
     * @param streamName: name of Kinesis stream 
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public void sendJson(JSONObject json, int partitionKey, String streamName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {
        try{
        PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
        putRecordRequest.setStreamName(streamName);
        putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(json.toString().getBytes("utf-8")));
        putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey(String.format("partitionKey-%d", partitionKey));
        kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   

    /**
     * Method useful to send the json Array to Kinesis
     * @param json: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject Array to be sent
     * @param partitionKey: partition key for Kinesis stream
     * @param streamName: Kinesis stream name
     */
    public void sendJsonArray(JSONArray json,int partitionKey, String streamName) {
        try{
        PutRecordsRequest putRecordsRequest = new PutRecordsRequest();
        putRecordsRequest.setStreamName(streamName);            
        List <PutRecordsRequestEntry> putRecordsRequestEntryList  = new ArrayList<PutRecordsRequestEntry>();
        for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){           
            PutRecordsRequestEntry putRecordsRequestEntry  = new PutRecordsRequestEntry();
            putRecordsRequestEntry.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(json.getJSONObject(i).toString().getBytes("utf-8")));
            putRecordsRequestEntry.setPartitionKey(String.format("partitionKey-%d", partitionKey));
            putRecordsRequestEntryList.add(putRecordsRequestEntry); 
        }
        putRecordsRequest.setRecords(putRecordsRequestEntryList);
        kinesisClient.putRecords(putRecordsRequest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [PutRecords API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) sample request should look as

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: kinesis.<region>.<domain>
x-amz-Date: <Date>
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Credential>,     SignedHeaders=content-type;date;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target;x-  amzn-requestid, Signature=<Signature>
User-Agent: <UserAgentString>
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
Content-Length: <PayloadSizeBytes>
Connection: Keep-Alive 
X-Amz-Target: Kinesis_20131202.PutRecords
```

So at least the following are required:

- Content-Type
- X-Amz-Target
- Authorization
- x-amz-date

You can add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to add them to your requests.

JMeter should populate Content-Length, Connection and Host on his own.

Comment: thanks, but I have only User Name, Access Key Id, Secret Access Key, how can i make an http header throught this value? I think that the problem is the signature . I am also trying to import AmazonKinesisClient into Jmeter so that I will be able to use Beanshell but the import doesn't work (in the jar file the class doesn't exist but in eclipse the import is correct)

Comment: eventually I used Amazon Kinesis API through java code in Jmeter

Comment: @luca would you mind sharing your java code as an answer? It would be helpful for other's looking for a solution.