# Load testing AWS Kinesis stream with JMeter error: unable to resolve class com.amazonaws.services.kinesis

Tags: jmeter, aws-sdk, performance-testing, load-testing, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to use the AWS-SDK and Kinesis Client library with JMeter to produce records to put into my Kinesis stream for performance testing purposes. My issue is that JMeter will not recognize the libraries to be able to call them from my code. I am at a loss as to what to troubleshoot next.

Installed JMeter 5.0 (I tried with version 4.0 with same issues) and Java 8.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_202-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-ea-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b03, mixed mode)
```

Placed JAR files for the AWS libraries in the lib folder of my JMeter installation (also tried lib/ext):

```
- amazon-kinesis-client-2.1.0.jar
- aws-java-sdk-1.11.490.jar
- aws-sdk-java-2.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
- aws-sdk-java-aws-core-2.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
- aws-sdk-java-kinesis-2.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
- aws-sdk-java-sdk-core-2.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

(also added these three based on another post - not sure if they are really needed or not)

```
- jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar
- jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
- jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
```

JSR223 sampler using Groovy code (based on other examples):

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.CreateStreamRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamResult
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ListStreamsRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ListStreamsResult
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordResult
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ResourceNotFoundException
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.StreamDescription

    class AmazonKinesisRecordProducerSample {

         def kinesis

        def init() {

            AWSCredentials credentials = null
              credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials()
              kinesis = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials)         
        }    
    }

    def amazonKinesisRecordProducerSample= new AmazonKinesisRecordProducerSample() 
    amazonKinesisRecordProducerSample.init()
    def Environment = vars.get("Environment") //as String
    def AWS_Region = vars.get("AWS_Region") //as String

    def myStreamName="stream123-" + Environment + "-" + AWS_Region

        def jsondata = new JsonBuilder()
        jsondata {
            <VARIOUS JSON DATA ADDED>
        }
        def data=jsondata.toPrettyString()
        log.info("jsondata: " + data)
        def partitionkey="<PARTITION KEY>"
        def putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest()
        putRecordRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName)
        putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(String.valueOf(data).getBytes()))
        putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey(partitionkey)
        def putRecordResult = new PutRecordResult()
        putRecordResult = amazonKinesisRecordProducerSample.kinesis.putRecord(putRecordRequest)
        log.info("Successfully put record, partition key : %s, ShardID : %s, SequenceNumber : %s.\n",
                    putRecordRequest.getPartitionKey(),
                    putRecordResult.getShardId(),
                    putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber())
```

I get this error for every com.amazonaws.* I try to import:

```
Script1.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient
 @ line 14, column 1.
   import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient
```

for reference 
[How to put 25k record to kinesis stream and Test tool to acknowledge it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936726/how-to-put-25k-record-to-kinesis-stream-and-test-tool-to-acknowledge-it) and [Using HTTP Request of Jmeter to put records into Amazon Kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031477/using-http-request-of-jmeter-to-put-records-into-amazon-kinesis)

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `com.amazonaws.services.kinesis` classes you may:

1. drop `aws-java-sdk-1.11.490.jar` to `JMeter\lib` from [AWS SDK for Java 1.11.0](http://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip)
2. Restart JMeter

Also, note

> `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext` used for JMeter components and plugins
>   Other jars (such as JDBC, JMS implementations and any other support libraries needed by the JMeter code) should be placed in the `JMETER_HOME/lib` directory - not the lib/ext directory, or added to `user.classpath`.

Comment: Thanks - I did try the jar files in the lib directory to no avail. I have also tried the one that you mention (aws-java-sdk-1.11.490.jar) and it does not change the outcome either (I added this to the description above)

Comment: Forget to ask - did you restart JMeter after you dropped aws-java-sdk-1.11.490.jar into JMeter\lib?

Comment: ^ yes I restarted Jmeter

Comment: And after steps 1 and 2 is the error message remains the same? Because probably there is may rise another exception.

Comment: As mentioned, I tried all of the suggestions provided and am still getting the same response - It is not finding the libraries properly. Any other ideas of things to try?